# Which functions of a normally distributed random variable are also normally distributed

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, transformation

I know that if $X$ is normal then $Y$ = $f(X)$ = $aX + b$ is normal, and this is covered in other questions.

Are there any other cases?

Comment: I am fairly certain the answer is No, but I cannot argue for it, so I'll just leave this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be a continuous function such that $Y=f(X)$. Then, $$f_Y(y)=f_X(f^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy}(f^{-1}(y))\right|\tag{1}$$ If $\ Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, it follows that $$f_Y(y)=f_X\left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\frac{1}{\sigma}\tag{2}$$ Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$, it is seen that $f(y)=\sigma y+\mu$ is the only possible choice for $f$.

Comment: For future reference (1) is the "change of variable technique"

Comment: I'm being a bit stupid.. how does (2) follow from (1) without assuming some form for f(). Don't we need to arrive at (2) without assuming (1)?

Comment: Your question asks if there is $Y$ which follows normal distribution. So assume that it is normal and then compare the density with (1)

Comment: (2) follows from the PDF definitions directly and not from (1).